# Searching a node in tree structure .txt file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `.txt` file with a tree structure, which looks like this:

```
R  R1   1        "Template for setting parameters"  ENGLISH        1                      1
U U1    "Any user"   ENGLISH   100%      1

 A A1   "Setup stim levels" 0min          0           0%           AVAILABLE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

  B SA1 1 "Engine tests"
   M CH1 1 1 120mA 10us 450us 40Hz ASYM "Channel 1"
   M CH2 1 2 120mA 10us 450us 40Hz ASYM "Channel 2"
   M CH3 1 3 120mA 10us 450us 40Hz ASYM "Channel 3"

   P P0 "Phase zero" 0ms NONE 2000ms STOP STOP STOP   
    O CH1 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE
    O CH2 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE
    O CH3 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE

   P P1 "Phase one" 0ms NONE 2000ms STOP STOP STOP  
    O CH1 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE
    O CH2 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE
    O CH3 0mA  0ms    0ms   600000ns 180us RATE


@--------
```

Here each node has only one parent, its reference is unique amongst its siblings (e.g. `P0`, `P1` etc.)

I can search for values in a children (look for lines starts with  `"O CH"`) by splitting the lines as follows:

```
        QString filename = "config_keygrip";
            QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/"+filename+".txt";

            QFile originalFile(path);
            originalFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text); 
            while (!originalFile.atEnd()) {
                QByteArray line = originalFile.readLine();
                if (line.contains("O CH")) {
                    QStringList list = QString::fromUtf8(line).split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);

                    qDebug()<<"Extracted values are: "<< list[1]<< list[2]<<list[3]<< list[4]<< list[5]<<"and"<<list[6];
                }

            }
    originalFile.close();
```

the above code gives me values form all the children.

I'm a bit stuck at how to search for a particular node's children.

For ex. By clicking a `pushButton` called `NEXT` how to get into nodes one by one and extract children values (as above)?

Comment: Take a blank sheet of paper and a pen. Write down, using short, brief, plain English sentences, a step by step process to accomplish this task. When done, [schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished. P.S. The shown code is fundamentally flawed. What do you think the shown code does with a line that reads `B SA1 1 "Foo O CH bar"`?

Comment: i would start by writing a data structure representing the tree and read all the contents into that data structure instead of trying to extract the desired information on the fly

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 , how do I traverse into a particular node children? could you show me an example?

Comment: honestly I think you didnt understand my comment. I suggest you to forget about details such as "how to get a particular node" for a moment and first define a data structure that holds all the contents of the file, then write code to read the file into that data structure. I cannot help you with that because I dont really know how to interpret the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am assuming that indentation is significant here, ie children are more indented than their parents. It also assumes that nesting levels are exactly one space apart.

Let's start with a simple `Node` struct:

```
struct Node {
    Node * parent;
    char tag;
    QString reference;
    QString full_line;
    QVector<Node *> children;
};
```

First, write a function that processes a line and returns an `std::optional<std::pair<int, Node*>>`. This will either return an empty value (if there is nothing to read on that line) or a pair of (indentation level, new Node).

```
std::optional<std::pair<int, Node*>> process_line(QString line) {
    int indentation = 0;
    while (line.size() > indentation && line[indentation] == ' ') {
      indentation++;
    }
    line = line.mid(indentation);
    if (line.isEmpty())
        return std::nullopt; // This line only contains spaces, return nothing.

    Node * ret = new Node;
    ret->parent = nullptr;
    QTextStream ts(&line);
    ts >> ret->tag >> ret->reference;
    ret->full_line = line;

    return std::make_pair(indentation, ret);
}
```

Then create a loop that processes each line of the file.
Keep track of a stack of `Node *` elements, which is initially just the root node.
For each line in the file, pass it to `read_line` and implement the following logic:

- If `read_line` returned `nullopt`: do nothing.
- Else, inspect the indentation level of the returned pair against the current stack of nodes:

  - If `indentation == nodes.size() - 1`: this is a child of the current top node. Set `new_node->parent = nodes.top()` and `nodes.top()->children.push_back(new_node)`. Push `new_node` onto the node stack.
  - If `indentation < nodes.size() - 1`: pop `nodes` until `indentation == nodes.size() - 1`, then do as above.

You now have a tree where you can navigate downwards (via `children`) and upwards (`parent`).